# Two sample T-test on Employment Data

Tags: r, t-test

I'm trying to conduct a two sample t-test on [this data](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/SMU53426607072200001SA) on food and drink workers in the Seattle MSA to see if there is a mean difference in levels of employment before and after the enactment of an increase in the minimum wage after April 1, 2015. The background for this project is that many people say that an increase in the minimum wage will force low-skill employers to cut their staff in order to minimize costs.

I've included my code below but I'm not certain it's correct. I separated the data into two variables (observations before and after the minimum wage increase took effect), but why am I getting such a ridiculously small P-value? Is that correct? Any help is appreciated.

```
#seattleData <- read.table(file=file.choose(), 2 # header=T, sep=",",)
food_drink_workers <- seattleData$food_drink_workers
afterMinWageLaw <- food_drink_workers[304:346]
beforeMinWageLaw <- food_drink_workers[1:303]
boxplot(beforeMinWageLaw, afterMinWageLaw)
options(scipen = 100)
t.test(beforeMinWageLaw, afterMinWageLaw, mu=0, 
    alternative "less", conf=.95, 
    var.equal = FALSE, paired = FALSE)
```

Results:

```
Welch Two Sample t-test 
data: beforeMinWageLaw and afterMinWageLaw 
t = -36.92, df = 160.8, p-value < 0.00000000000000022 
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is less than 0
 95 percent confidence interval: 
-Inf -38.87279 
sample estimates: 
mean of x mean of y 
103.8059 144.5023
```